# Can I write a Objective-C class method like this?

Tags: objective-c, static, class-method

For convenience to use,I write a SBJsonParser Category named Addition:

```
@implementation SBJsonParser(Addition)

+ (NSDictionary *)parseJson:(NSData *)data {
    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *dict = [parser objectWithData:data]; 
    [parser release];
    return dict;
}

@end
```

My questions are:

1. Is it right?
2. The pointer parser in class method is static?If not,should I declare it to static?
3. the pointer parser needs to release?

Answer (score 2):

1. Looks okay, if you know for sure that the JSON data contains a dictionary and not an array.
2. No, and no. `parser` is local, and doesn't need to be anything else if the `-objectWithData:` method is synchronous.
3. Yes.

Comment: Thank you Caleb,then I want ask you another question,the objective-c class method isn't like the static method in C++,yes?When it in C++,the static method and it's local variebles is static also.

Comment: @Gin: Yes, there are a number of important differences between C++'s static methods and Objective-C's class methods — not the least of which is that, since class methods are actually methods on the class object, there is a `self` in class methods — the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be well formed and correct overall

You don't have to use the static keyword for parser in the case.

Yes, you need to release parser and you've done it in the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

1) it looks fine

2) it is not. you should not.

3) it is fine as it is

Answer (score 1):

It fine. Parser is not status it is regular local variable but since you release it anyway so what. Yes parser needs to be released